# jquery mobile simulate dialog box over div

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got a list view in my content area.

Looking to create a "overlay" over the listview to let the user know that we are looking for updates.

from my fetch controller I call:

```
$('#listview').addClass('loading');
```

But nothing happens.

page looks like:

```
<div data-role="content" id="content">
<ul data-role="listview" id="listview">
<% @places.each do |p| %>
  <li>
      <a href="#"><%= p.name %></a>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>   
</div>
```

CSS has:

```
#listview {
  position:relative;
}

.loading {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: try $('#listview').addClass('loading').listview('refresh');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS mistake ?

```
backgournd
background
```

Comment: I wish.  It was a typo from typing the question out. :(

Comment: Why not trying to add a div on document with 100% size and bg alpha?

Answer (score 2):

What about using the jQuery mobile page loading message (the same one that shows when transitioning between pages)

You can show it using `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();` and hide it using `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();`

Here's the link to the [relevant part of the jQuery mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/methods.html).

Comment: OK, adding this to my fetch controller it does not work, but adding it after the controller has fetched all the data and reloaded the page it does show up.